# Best Way to Scale This Series with Outliers

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas Dataframe where most series are distributed similar to X as shown below. 90% of the data points lie between a small range, for example -0.5 and 0.5 in the series below contains 96.9% of observations , but then the tails have outliers that are several orders of magnitude larger than the rest of the distribution. The problem is that I have investigated all of these outliers, and they are not bad data. Furthermore, from experience totally excluding those data points would significantly bias my analysis in a predictable way. Can anyone suggest a normalization or standardization process that could help with this situation. I have tried off the shelf scalers like StandardScaler() and RobustScaler() from sklearn and I have tried shifting the distribution to have a minimum of 1 so that I could then take the log of the distribution but none of these approaches are working to achieve my goal of a nice spread of data to be input into a neural network.

[image: Original Series Descriptive Stats]

[image: Original Series Distribution Plot]

[image: Code to Zoom in]

[image: Descriptive Stats of Zoomed In]

[image: Distribution of Zoomed In]

Comment: Have you tried box-cox - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html ??

Comment: Try with a logarithmic transformation

Comment: @m33n I can't do a pure log transform because my series has negative. I shifted all series to min val of 1 and then took the log but it didn't help.